# Changing permissions of Apache server giving 403 when requesting images and CSS

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mac-osx

I have Apache running on my Mac (Snow Leopard). On my local dev machine my site cannot access images and CSS files that are hosted. Access to these directories is denied with a 403 Forbidden error.

I assume that I need to change permissions at the web server.

Can someone send me in the right direction to find out how I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001881/correct-owner-group-permissions-for-apache-2-site-files-folders-under-mac-os-x-1) may be your answer. I haven't used Apache on a Mac myself but the permission structure seems to be the same as on Linux. You can either make the directories/files all world readable (`chmod o+r`), or assign user/group ownership to the files like in the linked question.

If that question doesn't solve things or you need further details just let me know.