# How to set Apache to return 403 on images used as CSS backgrounds

Tags: apache-2.2, http-status-code-403, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent hot linking (“image theft” / “bandwidth theft”) of ressources on my site?](https://serverfault.com/questions/300089/how-to-prevent-hot-linking-image-theft-bandwidth-theft-of-ressources-on)

I'd like to configure my Apache server similar to a working configuration I noticed on the [Farming Simulator](http://www.farming-simulator.com) website. They use CSS background images for their main navigation bar but if you try to view an image with a direct link ([example](http://www.farming-simulator.com/img/bg/sprite.png)) it returns a 403 Forbidden error. I know how to allow/deny indexes for directories, but not how to deny access to files within those directories.

Does anyone know how I'd go about configuring .htaccess to work like this?

I found a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/272151/changing-permissions-of-apache-server-giving-403-when-requesting-images-and-css) but it doesn't really answer mine.

Answer (score 1):

First I want to tell you that this is a very futile act. As soon as you see the image in your browser, it has been downloaded to your computer.

When I followed your link directly I had a 403. Then I visited the page and I could even see the image in the link because it was in the cache.

I believe this effect is produced by examining the referer of the request. A sample for blocking by referer can be found [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess14.shtml)

I still recomend you not to do it. Not many people try to hotlink a background image. And if they really want to, it's still easy to overcome this measure by simply changing the header.